# How can I convert an LDAP user to local user in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

We have a [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com) install, currently using LDAP for authentication. Is it possible to convert an LDAP GitLab account to a regular local GitLab account? If yes, how is this done.

I can’t find anything in the admin console, and Google doesn’t seem to give anything useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bah, I should of held off asking for just a little longer! How to convert an LDAP user to a regular local user in Gitlab 8:

1. Log in as an administrator
2. From the admin console,  click the *Users* tab
3. Click on the user you want to change. Note that there's a UI quirk in GitLab. If you select *Edit* on the user, the setting is nowhere to be found, you have to click on their name to get the setting!
4. Click on the *Identities* tab for the user
5. Delete the LDAP identity

You can then give the user a new password, OR they can password reset from the login page.

Comment: While I can delete the LDAP identity using these steps and then successfully change the password (causing a mail to be send to the user), login using the new password fails for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself needing to remove LDAP from all your users at once, you can `DELETE FROM identities;` in gitlab's postgres database.

1. As Gitlab's documentation is awash with warnings not to tamper directly with their database, you may want to run `gitlab-backup` first just to be safe.
2. Get a shell logged in as gitlab's `git` user. If you've installed using docker, the command is:

   ```
   docker exec -it gitlab su - git
   ```

   If you've installed using one of the other methods, it's this:

   ```
   su - git
   ```
3. Launch the gitlab-embedded postgres client:

   ```
   /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql gitlabhq_production gitlab
   ```
4. Issue the SQL Command:

   ```
   delete from identities;
   ```